Why didn’t Tulasidas write Ramacharitamanas in Hindi/Hindustani?
Hindi…or at the time Hindustani was far more prevalent than Awadhi if I’m not wrong. Online I found he wrote it in Awadhi to increase the reach of his work. Wouldn’t writing it in Hindi popularise it even more?

Hindustānī (as you know it now) was not prevalent in the time of Tulasīdāsa, it became prevalent quite later. At that time, Avadhī and Braj was quite popular in and around the parts where Tulasīdāsa lived though.
